# Cannot Run/Install/Uninstall a ClickOnce application

Tags: .net, clickonce

My office recently migrated user account profiles to a different domain.

Once the user is migrated to the new domain they cannot start, uninstall or re-install the deployed .NET application. This is an issue with many of my deployed applications on different .NET frameworks (2.0 & 3.5). When I try to uninstall the app (Control Panel --> Add or Remove Programs) nothing happens. I click Change/Remove, the PC stalls for a second and nothing happens.

One user reported a problem with DFSVC.EXE and an "Unknown Software" error message.

The users still have full permission on the server where the app is published.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.